# avoid javax.servlet.ServletException

Tags: java, jsp, jsf

I am getting a javax.servlet.servletException while executing the following code....

"<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>

"<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>

"<%@ taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/tiles" prefix="tiles"%>

tiles:importAttribute scope="request" />

h:panelGrid columns="2" >

```
<f:facet name="header">
    <f:subview id="header">
        <tiles:insert attribute="header" flush="false" />
    </f:subview>
</f:facet>

<f:subview id="menu">
    <tiles:insert attribute="menu" flush="false" />
</f:subview>

<f:subview id="content">
    <tiles:insert attribute="content" flush="false" />
</f:subview>
```

Comment: Need a stack trace. And please format the complete code. It looks like you got some unopened/unclosed tags, that might be occured while pasting. Please edit your post to correct the issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question does not appear to be well formed XML.  There are tag endings but no beginnings.  Are you sure the text didn't get mangled when you submitted the question?